# Will implementing IXMLSerializable create a serializer DLL file in my Temp directory?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, ixmlserializable

Normally, when using the XMLSerializer to automagically serialize an ISerializable object, a .dll file is generated on C:\WINDOWS\Temp.

If I implement IXMLSerializable instead, where I'm telling it how to serialize / deserialize, will it also generate this DLL?
I have a very simple class to serialize, and I'm trying to avoid this automatic generation of files, for permissions reasons.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using IXmlSerializable won't keep it from creating an assembly. In order to do that, in the project properties, look:

1. On the Build tab for C#, there's a "Generate Serialization Assembly" dropdown.
2. On the Compile tab for VB.NET, there's an "Advanced Compile Options" button. Click it, and you'll find a "Generate Serialization Assemblies" dropdown.

In both cases, you can set it to "Off" and manually use the [XML Serializer Generator Tool (Sgen.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240.aspx) to generate your assemblies.